# How to check if an existing specific user (say techxhelp) is logged in and then logout that specific user in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-users

I want to do something like this in views.

This is not a perfect code. I am just giving an example of what is my requirement.

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.techxhelp is_logged_in:
            logout(techxhelp)
    else:
            pass
```

I tried searching Google and different sites but I found nothing.
If anyone knows the solution, I shall be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply determine the **Id** of the **specific user** you are intending to logout, then you can implement something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

BAD_USER = 1337 # assuming the user's Id is '1337'

def home(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.id == BAD_USER and user.is_authenticated(): # might differ depending on your auth-system.
            logout(request)
    # ...
    else:
            pass
```

Alternate method as requested in comments:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

BAD_USER = "techxhelp" # assuming the user's username is 'techxhelp'

def home(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated() and user.username == BAD_USER: # might differ depending on your auth-system.
            logout(request)
    # ...
    else:
            pass
```

Comment: If the user is already logged in and is in a different device will it still work?
Like let us suppose home is login page and the user is logged in and now the user is trying to login again from a different device, will it detect the user is already logged in from the previous device?

Comment: @TechXHelp whether the user get's 'detected' or not depends entirely on whether he is logged in his current session and tries to access the URI associated with the view-function *home*. If he is logged in (which can mean different things depending on what authentication-method you're using) on whatever 'device', he is identified with every 'request' he sends to the server from it. Bear in mind, that 'device' should rather mean browser / session, where his unique sessionId is stored or gets send with the request as a cookie.

Comment: In user = request.user
can I use something like user = request.techxhelp
like username instead of user

Comment: @TechXHelp you could use: request.user.username, but then you will have to swap the positions of the 2 conditions in my if-statement. I would strongly recommend using the ID-method though instead of searching by username.

Comment: can I use logout(user) instead of logout(request)